# Phantom app Picture

Tags: phantom

Not really a tech question, but how can I set a custom icon in phantom Browser ?

[image: App without icon]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The icon/name that is displayed there is covered by this section in the docs: https://docs.phantom.app/best-practices/displaying-your-app .

Long story short you should have both a `<title>` element along with either a favicon or [apple touch icon](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/a/appletou.htm) on your home page that you're linking to.